# my app crashing on ipad because the releasing objects

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, release

I have developed application for ipad, already developed for iphone and works great but when moving to ipad I merged the pages together so the page has more than one table and too many objects
when open the main page it works sometimes but when I go to another page and try to go back to the main page the app crashes and gives this

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_autorelease:
0x3b61d660:  cbz    r0, 0x3b61d67a            ; objc_autorelease + 26
0x3b61d662:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x3b61d664:  movs   r2, #2
0x3b61d666:  ldr    r1, [r1, #16]
0x3b61d668:  bfi    r1, r2, #0, #2
0x3b61d66c:  ldrb   r1, [r1]
0x3b61d66e:  tst.w  r1, #2
0x3b61d672:  bne    0x3b61d67e                ; objc_autorelease + 30
0x3b61d674:  movs   r1, #0
0x3b61d676:  b.w    0x3b61e230                ; -[NSObject autorelease]
0x3b61d67a:  movs   r0, #0
0x3b61d67c:  bx     lr
0x3b61d67e:  movw   r1, #5170
0x3b61d682:  movt   r1, #503
0x3b61d686:  add    r1, pc
0x3b61d688:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0x3b61d68a:  b.w    0x3b60d5c0                ; objc_msgSend
0x3b61d68e:  nop
```

I have read many articles some of them said that it releasing objects already released and some of them is not helping at all telling that I should look for allocating but I don't know how to use it, tried but nothing works.

So please any one can help me with this issue?

Comment: We need to see some piece of code from your main screen, which crashes out for you. Yes indeed you are releasing an object which is already released. Maybe autoreleasing twice? Just check if that autorelease have been called again and again on the main screen, and specifically from the methods being called in ViewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear of main screen.

Comment: actually am using ARC so there is no autorelease

Comment: and for the code ,, i dont know what to give becuase i dont know where is the issue exactly

Comment: If your using some third party class make sure that view should use ARC or convert to ARC

Answer (score 1):

Overreleased objects are called zombies. If you look around on the net, you can find some help on how to use the profiler (Apple Instruments) to track them down.

Here are a couple of Apple links about zombie hunting.

- [Finding Messages Sent To Deallocated Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects/06_Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects.html)
- [Eradicating Zombies with the Zombies Trace Template](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW8)

Comment: sry but this is not helping i cant find a zombies